# Replace missing datapoints with the average of 2 other distant observations when there are multiple missing observations

Tags: r, na

I have a dataset of net hourly animal movements but there are several occasions where observers were periodically absent. I wish to replace the missing datapoints (in a new column) with the average of the same time period 24 hours before and after the missing datapoint.

Example data:

```
#Data Creation
Day1<- rep(1,24)
Day2<- rep(2,24)
Day3<- rep(3,24)
Day<- c(Day1,Day2,Day3)
Hour<- rep(0:23,3)
Net <- round(rnorm(length(Day),mean = 2))
Dat<- data.frame(Day= Day,Hour= Hour,Net= Net)

#Populate missing observations
Dat[27,3]<- NA
Dat[31,3]<- NA
Dat
```

I initially applied a function (below) that would locate a single missing value and then index the missing datapoint to locate and take the average of the rows 24 hours before and after the missing point.

```
Dat$new.net<- sapply(Dat[,3],function(x)  
   if_else(is.na(x), mean(c(Dat[which(is.na(Dat),arr.ind = T)[1]-24,3],Dat[which(is.na(Dat),arr.ind = T)[1]+24,3])),x))
```

I cannot find a way to make the function I used for 1 missing value work for multiple missing occasions, producing a unique average for each missing value. Currently the code only uses the average for the first missing value due to the "Dat[which(is.na(Dat),arr.ind = T)[1]"

How can I alter my code to work for multiple missing values, or is there a more elegant solution?

PS. I know I will have issues if there are missing values in the first or final 23 hours. I will cross that bridge when I get there.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could get the index of `NA` values and then subtract 24, add 24, to each of the elements, get the `rowMeans` after `cbind`ing and assign it to missing index

```
ind <- which(is.na(Dat[[3]]))
ind_minus <- ind - 24
ind_minus[ind_minus < 1] <- NA
ind_plus <- ind + 24
nd_plus[ind_plus > nrow(Dat)] <- NA

Dat[[3]][ind] <- rowMeans(cbind(Dat[[3]][ind_minus], Dat[[3]][ind_plus]),
     na.rm = TRUE)
```